# Difference of random variables conditioned on their sum

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Consider $\Omega = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ with sigma algebra of borel sets on $[0,1]^2$. Let $P$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$.
Let $$\xi(x, y) = x, \ \ \ \eta(x,y) = y.$$

How can I find $\mathbb{E}(\xi - \eta| \xi +\eta)$?

I tried to find out what $\sigma( \xi + \eta)$ and I've found that $$(\xi + \eta)^{-1}(a) = \{ (x, -a+x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ so it is a line.

But how do I do it in terms of general borel sets?

Could you help me with that?

Comment: By symmetry, it's zero.

Comment: @A.S. What kind of symmetry?

Comment: Between $\xi$ and $\eta$.

Comment: @A.S. We know that $$\mathbb{E}( \xi - \eta | \xi + \eta) = \mathbb{E}( \xi | \xi + \eta) - \mathbb{E}(\eta | \xi + \eta)$$. But why is $$\mathbb{E}( \xi | \xi + \eta) = \mathbb{E}(\eta | \xi + \eta)$$? How do we apply the symmetry here?

Comment: Because $x$ and $y$ are symmetric.

Comment: @A.S. Oh, so it is because $\int_A \mathbb{E}( \xi | \xi + \eta) dxdy = \int_A \xi dx dy = \int_A x dx dy = \int_A y dx dy = ...$ Don't we need to know what the set $A \in \sigma(\xi + \eta)$ looks like in order to justify this?